# Does the supported API features "transferring images" mean that i can transfer it to the app?

Tags: camera, sony

In the table of supported API features is the row "Transferring images". 
My Question: If it is not supported, i can take a picture but cannot transfer it to app? Or which "transfer" does it mean?

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring images refers to being able to transfer images from the camera to the phone or tablet using the API.  If it is not supported on a particular camera, it means you can take a picture and save it to the memory on the camera, but cannot transfer it to the phone or tablet via the API.

Comment: Will devices like the HDR-AS100V be updated to support this as well? Since the official Sony app is able to it I see no reason why it shouldn't be possible for any other app to do that.